# JavaScript closure and scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Here are the codes:

```js
function fn() {
  var x = 1;

  function fn2() {
    x++;
    console.log(x);
  }
  return fn2;
}
var foo = fn();
var bar = fn();
foo(); //2
bar(); //2  
foo(); //3
```

I got a problem that I can't figure out why the result is **not 2 3 4**.I mean,according the closure principle,foo and bar should have maintain the scope of the function **fn**,so I thought foo and bar have the same **x**.Hope you can help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` and `bar` don't share the same `x`. `x` gets created when `fn` is called. So each call to `fn` will create a brand new `x` which will be accessible by the brand defined function `fn2` that will be returned.

To check that `foo` and `bar` don't share the same `x`, here is an example:

```js
function fn() {
  var x = 1;

  function fn2() {
    x++;
    return x;
  }
  return fn2;
}
var foo = fn();
var bar = fn();
console.log("foo: " + foo());
console.log("bar: " + bar());
console.log("foo: " + foo());
console.log("foo: " + foo());
console.log("foo: " + foo());
console.log("foo: " + foo());
console.log("bar: " + bar());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the first function once and build a closure over `x` then return a function with a function inside.

```js
var fn = function () {        
    var x = 1;
    return function () {
        return function () {
            x++;
            console.log(x);
        };
    };
}();

var foo = fn();
var bar = fn();
foo(); //2
bar(); //3  
foo(); //4
```

Answer (score 0):

As var x creates a private variable, it's created anew each time fn() is assigned. If you WANTED it to carry over, simply change var x to this.x:

```js
fn = (function() {
  this.x = 1;

  function fn2() {
    this.x++;
    console.log(this.x);
  }
  return fn2;
});
var foo = fn();
var bar = fn();
foo(); //2
bar(); //3  
foo(); //4
```

Comment: I'm puzzled. What is `this` supposed to refer to here? It will be `undefined` in strict mode, and the window object otherwise. It's the same as declaring a global `x` variable. Also, I guess you mean "each time `fn()` is **called**, not "assigned".

Comment: `this.x` will make `x` global. It's as if `x` was defined outside the `fn` (globally). So then we are not talking about closures anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I was tinkering around and realized you're absolutely right. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

These two are the same call, hence `2` when you invoke them:

```
var foo = fn();
var bar = fn();
```

Both set `var x=1` privately. Therefore, when you call them again `foo(); //3` the inner function `fn2` is the one invoked with the increment statement